# How to add items to Combobox from Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, combobox

I have this code:

```
    private void FillCombobox()
    {
        using (InventoryEntities c = new InventoryEntities(Properties.Settings.Default.Connection))
        {
            List<Customer> usepurposes = c.Customers.ToList();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("id");
            dt.Columns.Add("name");
            foreach (Customer usepurpose in usepurposes)
            {
                dt.Rows.Add(usepurpose.id, usepurpose.name);
            }
            comboBox1.ValueMember = dt.Columns[0].ColumnName;
            comboBox1.DisplayMember = dt.Columns[1].ColumnName;
            comboBox1.DataSource = dt;

        }
    }
```

and I call this method in:

```
    private void frmBillIn_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FillCombobox();
    }
```

When I run my app, combobox will not display customers(items).

just display **Model.Customer**

What is the problem??

I tried many solution but non of them are working.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't have to mix two worlds, the world of Entity Framework and the world of DataSets. Bind directly:

```
    using (InventoryEntities c = new InventoryEntities(Properties.Settings.Default.Connection))
    {
        comboBox1.DataSource    = c.Customers;
        comboBox1.ValueMember   = "id";
        comboBox1.DisplayMember = "name";
    }
```

If this does not work, then the column name could be different from "name" ("Name" perhaps?).

Comment: I tried your code but I'm still getting the same result, I also tried to use "Name" but also the same result "Model.Customer"

Comment: I found the solution, OMG, I think I am so stupid, it was silly mistake, anyway thank you very much.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is just something with my code, but I had to change the DataSource to:  `c.Customers.ToList();'

Comment: what if i dont write(Properties.Settings.Default.Connection)?

Answer (score 7):

If you use "using" you need to place a ToList() for evaluate before close connection.
use ItemsSource , ValueMember and DisplayMember are case sensitive

```
using (InventoryEntities c = new InventoryEntities())
    {
        comboBox1.ItemsSource   = c.Customers.toList();
        comboBox1.ValueMemberPath   = "Id";
        comboBox1.DisplayMemberPath = "Name";
    }
```

Hope this help.

Comment: This helped me because the datasource, valuemember and displaymember were not showing with my code, but itemsource, valuememberpath... show just fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Refer following sample. (name references => DAL=Data access layer, projectEntities = entity set name) 
Hope this will help..

List itemsList = new List();

```
            using (DAL.projectEntities en = new DAL.projectEntities())
            {
                foreach (var item in en.tableName.Where(a => a.tableName != null).ToList())
                {
                    itemsList.Add(item.tableFieldName);
                }                                   
            }

            comboboxTable.ItemsSource = itemsList;
```

Answer (score 1):

In the current version of WinForms I have found this to work

```
RentalsEntities1 db = new RentalsEntities1();
        List<SiteSeeingLocation> ssloc = db.SiteSeeingLocations.ToList();
        cbSites.DataSource = ssloc;
        cbSites.ValueMember = "id";
        cbSites.DisplayMember = "ssLocation";
```