# Combobox add items from the list

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a combobox where I want to populate the list into it.
Currently, I am able populate the list but I am not able to display the string of it.

Here is the output its displaying from the combobox:

```
solution_name.folder_name.class_name
```

This is my user c# code:

```
userRoleList.Add(new User()
{
    UserRole = reader[1].ToString()
});
```

This is my xaml code:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cbUserRole" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" FontSize="16" Foreground="MidnightBlue" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" ItemsSource="{Binding}"/>
```

This is my viewuser c# code:

```
var userRolesList = new User().getUserRoles();
ComboBox cbUserRole = (ComboBox)GetChildren(userDataGrid).First(x => x.Name == "cbUserRole");
cbUserRole.ItemsSource = userRolesList;
```

How can I display the string in the combobox?

Comment: @ASh I have done that many times. I did my research before posting the question here.

Comment: @ASh the problem here is now I can populate the data from the database, but Its showing a different format as stated in my question

Comment: Maybe this answer can help you. https://stackoverflow.com/a/11747562/5106772

Comment: @Halim no it didnt help for my case.

Comment: The code you have supplied is ambiguous! What is the return type of `User.getUserRoles()`? You are using an implicitly typed local variable here, which makes it difficult to read without the rest of the code.